# MongoDB version 3.4 string number sorting with aggregate

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I've product sku number in string format like "500011" and I want to sort get all product with sku descending sort in mongoDB 3.4 version.

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate([
  {$match:{catId:'5e0af7cb6423d67d7d2a38d2'}},
  {$sort:{"sku": -1}}, //sku is a string number value like "500011"
])
```

Comment: Does [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/collation/#collation) do what you need?

Answer (score 3):

As Joe have mentioned the collation may help you here.

```
db.products.aggregate(
[{$sort: {"sku": -1}}], 
{collation: {locale: "en", numericOrdering: true}})
```

Example ouput:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e58d89fe0aba047483c3bbc"), "sku" : "500012" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e58d89de0aba047483c3bbb"), "sku" : "500011" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e58d8a3e0aba047483c3bbe"), "sku" : "404012" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e58d8a0e0aba047483c3bbd"), "sku" : "400012" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e58d8abe0aba047483c3bbf"), "sku" : "90000" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e58d8aee0aba047483c3bc0"), "sku" : "1000" }
```

But if **sku** in fact is always the number why not to save it as number to the database?
Then sort should work out of the box without any extra collation.

But be aware of:

> Collation and Index Use
>
> To use an index for string comparisons, an operation must also specify
>   the same collation. That is, an index with a collation cannot support
>   an operation that performs string comparisons on the indexed fields if
>   the operation specifies a different collation.

Because of that IMHO you should just store the **sku** as the number in the database if possible and sort it without any collation.